# Excel VBA - For Loop with specific values

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm trying to create a For Loop that only selects some values but can't work out the Syntax, or if it's even possible?

I want it to be like

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1,3,8,15 Then
Do something
Next i
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim indexArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    indexArr = Array(1, 3, 8, 15)
    For i = LBound(indexArr) To UBound(indexArr)
        Debug.Print indexArr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do following:

```
    Dim i as Variant
    Dim iArray as Variant
    iArray=Array(1,3,8,15)

    For Each i In iArray
         'Do Something
    Next i
```

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. OP wants to select only some values from the array. You've just demonstrated for loop syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

If there is a pattern you can use `Step`

```
For i = 1 to 15 Step 2
```

Which will do `1,3,5,7,...`

In this case since there is no pattern you will need to add an `If` or `Select Case`:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 to 15 Then
    Select Case i
        Case 1,3,8,15
             'Do Something
    End Select
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use if statement:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 15 Then
    If i = 1 or i = 3 or i = 8 or i = 15 Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next i
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This solution combines elements from the array solution above with the ease of use that I inferred was wanted by the OP. The array method requires looping through the array elements and then converting the array element back into a variable. This method skips 2 bits. Firstly, it skips the complex step logic of stepping through array elements. Secondly, it skips the step of converting an array element back into a usable variable.

```
Dim number_list as collection
set number_list = new collection

number_list.add 1
number_list.add 3
number_list.add 8
number_list.add 15

for each number in number_list
    'Do something with number
Next number
```

Comment: This *works*, but this seems like a big of a stretch - why bother declaring and creating a `Collection`?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This solution combines elements from the array solution above with the ease of use that I inferred was wanted by the OP. The array method requires looping through the array elements and then converting the array element back into a variable. This method skips 2 bits. Firstly, it skips the complex step logic of stepping through array elements. Secondly, it skips the step of converting an array element back into a usable variable. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is even a simplification of the routine of [Kedimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802937/kedimir):

Original question:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1,3,8,15 Then
  ' Do something
Next i
```

Solution:

```
Dim i As Variant
For Each i In Array(1, 3, 8, 15)
  ' Do something
Next i
```

For your information: the `Variant` is needed for the `For Each` loop, don't try to modify it into an integer, or the `For Each` loop won't be accepted.

I don't think that a more resembling solution is possible :-)